# lambdas and `const std::function&` arguments - minimizing copies

Tags: c++11, lambda

If I have code like this:

```
int executeTypeErased(const std::function<int()>& f)
{
    return f();
}

void test()
{
    executeTypeErased([] {
        return 42;
    });
}
```

When I call `test()`, am I guaranteed that no heap allocations occur due to the `std::function`?  I know that I am guaranteed that no heap allocations occur if I wrap this in a `std::reference_wrapper`, but I'm less certain with an undecorated lambda as an argument, promoted to `std::function`.

Comment: An instance of `std::function` is created here, initialized with a lambda object. I don't know of any rule that would prohibit `std::function`'s constructor from allocating memory. You could make it `executeTypeErased(+[] { return 42; });` - the `+` sign forces the conversion from lambda to a plain function pointer, and `std::function` initialized with a function pointer is required not to allocate. This would only work for a captureless lambda.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That `+` trick is fascinating.  Leave it to C++ to make curious idioms that have just the right type-system behaviors!  And of course, the alternative is to use `std::ref`, right?

Comment: Yes, that would work too (at least, `std::cref` should, probably not `std::ref`), including for lambdas with capture - assuming `executeTypeErased` won't attempt to stash that `function` somewhere to be called later. The function will hold a dangling reference once `executeTypeErased` returns.